# How do I find my program name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos7, rsyslog

## Problem

I am unable to write to a different log than the default one using syslog. I am unsure if maybe my app name is wrong in my configuration. Do "program name" and "process name" not mean the same thing? If not, how can I find my program name in Python 3.6?

## Attempted

I have written a small application in Python 3.6. I am already successfully writing to a common syslog file in CentOS 7 at `/var/log/messages` with it. If I open that file, I can see my entries.

If I run `ps aux | grep myappname`, the process name is listed as `python myappname.py`.

I have created a file at `/etc/rsyslog.d/00-myconfig.conf` which contents are:

```
if $programname contains 'myappname' then /home/user/test_log.log
& ~
```

I have restarted the process with `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`.

I have run `rsyslogd -N1` which gives me a deprecation warning about my use of `~` in my config, proving that the config is being recognized. I have tried removing that line as I am not sure what it does, but that does not help either.

I can confirm that the entries are still being written to `/var/log/messages`. The entries are not going up in smoke.

Comment: possibly helpful [How to check which specific processes (Python scripts) are running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/how-to-check-which-specific-processes-python-scripts-are-running) and [What is the difference between a job and a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-process)

Answer (score 0):

As syslog does not include the *appname* in a log naturally, you need to add it yourself when creating a log message. Here an example using the Linux *logger* command with `--tag`.

```
logger --tag="myappname" "Some message"
```

So before adjusting anything, check if your`rsyslog.conf` includes your files from `/etc/rsyslog.d/` (because they get checked even if you do not include them in your `rsyslog.conf`.

```
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf")
```

If the error persists, then your query has to be adjusted. The easiest way to do this, is using property-based filters.

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "myappname" /var/log/test_log.log

&~

*.* /var/log/messages
```

The config checks if `myappname` equals the `hostname` in the log. If so, it is written to `test_log.log`. The next line (`&~`) then discards all messages that have been written. Thus, no additional rules will be applied to these messages. As such, they will not be written to `/var/log/messages`.

**Important Note:** When using the compare operation `isequal`, the two values that are compared must be **exactly equal** (case-sensitive) to match. See the [rsyslog documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html) for more information on property-based filters.

---

**P.S.** Checkout [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1269643/why-does-mean-discard-the-messages-that-were-matched-in-the-previous-line) for further explanation on what `&~` means in rsyslog.